# Requesting re-open votes for a question

Tags: discussion, questions, closed-questions, close-reasons

I'm requesting that people vote to re-open this question: [What programs have trouble with case-sensitive (HFSX) filesystems, and how to fix them?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46322/what-programs-have-trouble-with-case-sensitive-hfsx-or-case-insensitive-hfs)

The reason for closing as given by the closer was:

> Since this kind of CW has fairly limited scope, appeal, and educational value, I'm closing this.

However, I disagree with some of those points. The educational value is potentially significant, not limited. The scope is narrow, but I don't think that is a valid reason to close, and the appeal may be limited, but maybe not. There are three other similar questions ([1](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/19486/can-i-convert-a-hfs-volume-to-hfsx-case-sensitive-without-extra-software-tool), [2](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/8016/hfs-case-sensitive-or-case-insensitive-which-type-to-use-for-the-primary-dri), [3](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32338/what-are-the-usage-cases-for-case-sensitive-hfsx-as-opposed-to-default-hfs)).

The main reason I think it should be re-opened is that it was closed less than one hour after it was asked, not very long. Furthermore, the two down-votes were given *after* it was closed, and were therefore very likely influenced by the fact that the question was closed. I'm not sure the question would have been down-voted if it had remained open.

Finally, the official (not comment) reason for the closing does not apply. I fail to see how this question would solicit `debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion`. To the contrary, this site and a community-wiki question seems like the ideal place for such a repository of facts. I can't think of a better location on the interwebs for this question and the possible answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After looking at this again I think it could be opened.

I don't completely remember my reasoning for closing it initially, but my guess is that I was worried that it would become a maintenance issue like the huger 'list of apps' wikis and I didn't think that it had a wide enough appeal to justify that kind of overhead.

But, after taking a second look, I think the question could be answered well with two big answers, one for each category (issues with case sensitive vs insensitive) containing a list of apps (like the [Genius Mixes answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/23660/2220)), which would be an effective way to collect the info and not nearly as much of a maintenance issue.

Or, as Mike suggests, this could be split into two distinct questions each with its own wiki answer.

How would you feel about reopening with a plan of doing something like that?

Thanks for bringing this up, and sorry for being perhaps too quick to close initially!

Comment: OK sounds good. I propose keeping one question. It is limited scope enough that two might spread it too thin. For example, there is only one program I am currently aware of that requires HSFX. So maybe it is 1 question: "HSFX Problems"? As for 1 big list like the Genius Mix, that is one approach. But if someone can provide code samples to get something working (http://www.jms1.net/osx-case-sensitive-fs.shtml), wouldn't that be useful? And therefore each program warrants its own answer. Why is this a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: See the comments above - even before things reach nightmare level, there is a downside to large questions. Moderating a question with three or more pages of answers is quite time consuming and we like to be open about why certain "rules" or habits exist so that we're being fair to all questions in a category (wiki - like) as well as this one in particular.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for raising this. My initial reaction is the site would be served by this opening again (well at least better served than my "notorious" tiny things in Lion question. Let's see what others think. The why some programs fail on case might be illuminating.

I almost think a pair of questions to keep each straight

- problem children on case-sensitive
- problem children on case-insensitive

Any comments on this?

Comment: As two mods have not objected to the opening - let's open it up and see how the community steps up. Let's count on @mankoff to pick the vision (one place for several CW answers listing each OR edit it to ask for one and perhaps ask another for the converse (case+ and case-).